# How can we save a value from a drop down button form field to the firebase in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dropdown

I have a flutter project linked to a firebase, and I had a problem linking the value from the drop-down box selected by the user when registering with the rest of the data entered in the same table

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Profession")
            .doc(result.user.uid)
            .set({
          'Full name': _fullName.text,
          'Email': _email.text,
        });
```

[image: img]

Comment: Can u provide, problem?

Comment: I want to save a value from the drop-down list to the database with other data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a sample dropdown

```
 String dropdownValue = 'One';
DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue;
        });
      },
      items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    )
```

on select something from dropdown the value will be stored in `dropdownValue`

then to store to firebase

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Profession")
            .doc(result.user.uid)
            .set({
          'fullName': _fullName.text,
          'email': _email.text,
           'myDropdownValue":dropdownValue

        });
```

PS: notice how i have saved my keys eg Full name to fullName...