# pass dropdown selected value to firebase collection in Dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

*Need to pass dropdown selected value from OrderListScreen to firebase collection order. Dont know the proper
way of passing this field value to be reflect in firebase. Code for dropdown is ok
need to get that selected value to be able to pass it to orderStatus field. Please help.*

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

class OrderListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OrderListScreen> createState() => _OrderListScreenState();
}

class _OrderListScreenState extends State<OrderListScreen> {
  String? newvalue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String dropdownvalue = 'Pending';
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(" Please select the order status from the dropdown Below:",
                style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.orange)),
            Container(
                child: Material(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                value: newvalue,
                items: <String>[
                  'Pending',
                  'Confirmed',
                  'Dispatched',
                  'Received'
                ].map((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String? newvalue) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.newvalue = newvalue;
                  });
                },
              ),
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write
Create reference of collection and update the value in OnChanged
Example - 
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users");

await ref.update({
  "123/age": 19,
  "123/address/line1": "1 Mountain View",
});

Comment: I have provided an answer below.Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66356274/18265638)

> on select something from dropdown the value will be stored in `dropdownValue`
>
> then to store to firebase

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("collection")
                .doc(result.user.uid)
                .set({
              'Name': _Name.text,
               'myDropdownValue":dropdownValue
    
            });
```